# Is there an SQL editor for the data itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm looking for an SQL (MSSQL) tool that will allow me to edit/insert/etc. data without the need to type sql statements. I want to simply enter data into a grid. I can't find this functionality in SSMS. Is there any tool that does that (preferably by MS)?

Comment: Right clicking a table and picking the edit option isn't sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Table Editor

If you right-click on a table in SSMS and click edit, you can edit the data in there directly.

[image: Table Editor]

---

### Query Designer

If you select a row or cell in the table editor, you have access to the Query Designer menu on the tool bar. By clicking on the pane menu, it will open a sub-menu that will give you access to the SQL, Criteria and a Diagram. This will allow you to design queries visually.

### [image: Query Designer]

Answer (score 3):

SSMS does let you do it, although it's not a great tool by any stretch. If you right click on a table and go to Edit Top 100 rows, you can get the grid. If you want to be able to edit any number of rows, go to Tools -> Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Commands and change both values in the Table and View options to 0, which means unlimited.

You can also edit the query that is used to generate the grid. In the toolbar, there's a button that says SQL and the hovertext is "Show SQL Pane". You can then edit the SQL to include/exclude columns or add conditions. This may help with large tables. You can also use this method to overcome the row number limit if you didn't change the defaults as in the above paragraph.

Comment: Thanks. That bit about changing the number of rows is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the table in SSMS and click Edit Top 200 Rows:[image].

Answer (score 0):

Using MS SQL Managment Studio you can right click on a table and select Edit. This will let you edit existing rows and add new rows by just typing into the 'grid'.

Answer (score 0):

try this. may be this can help

http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10392.editing-an-sql-server-table-in-excel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A real easy thing to do is to use Access as a front end to SQL Server. It would take only a few minutes to create an ODBC connection from Access to SQL Server and you can quickly use Access's grids and forms to enter data.